# How to get rid of this white background color on all variables in Padre Perl IDE

Tags: perl, padre

Padre is always my favourite IDE for Perl. I downloaded from here: 
http://code.google.com/p/dwimperl/downloads/detail?name=dwimperl-5.14.2.1-v7-32bit.exe&can=2&q=

I have one small problem. There is white block (like background color) around all variables, as shown in the attached image. This is on a XP machine. Most of other machines are not like this. How can I get rid of it?

[image]
http://tinypic.com/r/316x1ug/8

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki: Padre syntax highlighting](http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/Features/SyntaxHighlighting)

Follow this link. Go to the menu options, look for a backgroundcolor: entry. Then remove it and make it the correct color you want.

Otherwise create your own YML file for highlighting.

I would be more specific IF I could actually install padre, but this should get you in the right direction.